# Jquery, how to dynamically load group of iframe?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically load multiple iframe with a single dropdown, the iframe are grouped, meaning if I choose a item in the dropdown it should show the group of iframe, however I cant get it to work, this is how I coded it:

```
HTML
<select id="color"> 
<option label="red" id="red" value="http://red></option>
<option class="hide" id="red1" value="http://red1></option>

<option label="blue" id="blue" value="http://blue></option>
<option class="hide" id="blue1" value="http://blue1></option>

</select>

<div><iframe id="iframeId" src=""></iframe></div>
<div><iframe id="iframeId1" src=""></iframe></div>

JQUERY

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("color").change(function(){

   $("#iframeId").attr("src",$("this").attr("color:selected")val());
   $("#iframeId1").attr("src",$("this").attr("color:selected")val());

  });
 });
```

any idea, what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
       $(".color").change(function(){
           var check_color = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
           check_select(check_color);
    });
       var check_select = function(check_color){
        //console.log(check_color);
        var values_options = [];
           values_options.push(check_color);
            $(".color>option").each(function(index,element){
               var id_check = $("#"+check_color+index).attr('id');
               if(typeof id_check!="undefined"){
                values_options.push(id_check)
               }
                 
           });
          //  console.log(values_options);
             var idframe = []
       $("iframe").each(function(value){
           idframe.push($(this).attr('id'));
       });
       
       //console.log(idframe);
       //for change iframe
       
       for(var i=0;i<idframe.length;i++){
         $("#"+idframe[i]).attr('src',$(".color>option#"+values_options[i]).val());
        // console.log($(".color>option#"+values_options[i]).val());
       
       }
       }
       var color = $(".color").children(":selected").attr("id");
    check_select(color);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="color"> 
    <option label="red" id="red" data-id="red" value="https://router.vuejs.org/api/#component-injected-properties">   </option>
  <option class="hide" id="red1" value="https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html"></option>
  
  <option label="blue" id="blue" value="https://api.jquery.com/each/"></option>
   <option class="hide" id="blue1" value="https://ping.eu/ping/"></option>
</select>

<div><iframe id="iframeId" src=""></iframe></div>
<div><iframe id="iframeId1" src=""></iframe></div>
```

Comment: thanks @skipperhoa, the code you wrote looks like is capturing the red group only, and left the blue group totally, what I am looking to achieve is if the RED was chosen the iframe will load the "http://red and "http://red1 if the BLUE was chosen the iframe will load the "http://blue and "http://blue1

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color").change(function(){
      $("#iframeId").attr("src",$('#color option:selected').val());
     $("#iframeId1").attr("src",$('#color option:selected').val());
    });
  });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<select id="color"> 
      <option label="red" id="red" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PCwL3-hkKrg"> red</option>

      <option label="blue" id="blue" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EngW7tLk6R8"> blue</option>
  </select>
<div><iframe id="iframeId" src=""></iframe></div>
<div><iframe id="iframeId1" src=""></iframe></div>
```

you have to change jquery code to following

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#color").change(function(){
            $("#iframeId").attr("src",$('#color option:selected').val());
            $("#iframeId1").attr("src",$('#color option:selected').val());
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidy up the script part from the @skipperhoa's answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {          
 $("#color").change(function() {
  $('#iframeId').attr('src', $(this).find('option:selected').val());
  $('#iframeId1').attr('src', $(this).find('option:selected').next().val());        
 });
 $("#color").change();
});

function addIframe() {
 var src = 'https://ping.eu/ping/';
 $('<div><iframe id="iframeId' + $('iframe').length + '" src="' + src + '"></iframe></div>').insertAfter($('iframe:last').parent());
}
function addIframeBefore(id) {
 var src = 'https://ping.eu/ping/';
 $('<div><iframe id="iframeId' + $('iframe').length + '" src="' + src + '"></iframe></div>').insertBefore($(id).parent());
}
function addIframeafter(id) {
 var src = 'https://ping.eu/ping/';
 $('<div><iframe id="iframeId' + $('iframe').length + '" src="' + src + '"></iframe></div>').insertAfter($(id).parent());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Add New iframe after last iframe" onclick="addIframe()">
<input type="button" value="Add New iframe before iframe1" onclick="addIframeBefore('#iframeId1')">
<input type="button" value="Add New iframe after iframe1" onclick="addIframeafter('#iframeId1')">
<select id="color"> 
 <option label="red" id="red" data-id="red" value="https://router.vuejs.org/api/#component-injected-properties"></option> 
 <option class="hide" id="red1" value="https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html"></option>
 <option label="blue" id="blue" value="https://api.jquery.com/each/"></option>
 <option class="hide" id="blue1" value="https://ping.eu/ping/"></option>
</select>

<div><iframe id="iframeId" src=""></iframe></div>
<div><iframe id="iframeId1" src=""></iframe></div>
```

Comment: if position <option> different, it does not work, example: <option id="red"></option><option id="blue"></option>, it does not get id position the same

Comment: Hi @karan, this code work perfect, thank you! what if I wanted to add more iframe?

Comment: Updated code for Dynamically add iframe to the last, or append before or after any iframe.